react-date-picker tile disabled not working
I have a project https://www.motoschool.co.nz/ with a booking section using react-date-picker. This was previously working with blocked off dates coming from datocms, but now even passing an inline tileDisabled function isn't working e.g.
<DatePicker tileDisabled={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => date.getDay() === 0} />

Has anyone else had a similar experience or knows what could be going wrong or how to troubleshoot? I've already commented out and rebuilt everything based on the old website, which is working. I’ve also tried inline functions, clearing the cache with gatsby clean, reinstalling packages, etc., but I'm not sure why the tiles wouldn't be disabled.
Any tips or suggestions for alternative calendar component would be appreciated!
Full page code below:
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from "react"
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";
import { isWithinInterval } from "date-fns";
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker'
import 'react-date-picker/dist/DatePicker.css';
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';

const FormDiv = styled.div`
width: 694px;
// margin-right: 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
form {
    // padding: 50px;
    width: 694px;
    // margin-right: 20px;
    // max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    // background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    .select-style {
        // background-color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        :hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
    .button-style {
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        transition: .3s;
        :hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            // background-color: #635bff;
        }
    }
           .back {
    width: 28%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    }
    .next {
    width: 70%;
    }

    label {
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-top: 50px;
        // margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
    input{
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
        transition: .3s;
    }
    // input:hover {
    //     border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    // }
    input:focus-visible, textarea:focus-visible {
        border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        outline: 0;
    }
}
.time-selection {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        // justify-content: space-between;
        div {
            // border: solid 2px white;
            border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
            border-radius: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 14px 14px;
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 1px 2px;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            transition: .3s;
            // background-color: grey;
            :hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            }
        }
        .active-time {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
}
.grecaptcha-badge { visibility: hidden!important; }
.recaptcha-sub {
font-size: 14px;
color: hsla(40,22%,92%,.6);
}
.react-date-picker__wrapper {
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
//   border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  :hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  input {
  border: none;
  }
  input:focus-visible {
  border: none;
  }
}
.react-date-picker__calendar-button__icon, .react-date-picker__clear-button__icon {
stroke: white;
transition: .3s;
}
.react-date-picker__inputGroup__input {
padding: 0;
}
@media(max-width: 940px){
    width: 90vw!important;
    form {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90vw!important;
}

`

// function isWithinRange(date, range) {
//     console.log("isWithinRangeRunning", date, range)
//     return isWithinInterval(date, { start: range[0], end: range[1] });
// }
// function isWithinRanges(date, ranges) {
//     console.log("isWithinRangesRunning", date, ranges)
//     return ranges.some(range => isWithinRange(date, range));
// }
// let in3Days = new Date(2024, 11, 28);
// let in5Days = new Date(2024, 11, 28);
// let in13Days = new Date(2024, 11, 30);
// let in15Days = new Date(2024, 11, 31);

// let testDays = new Date(2024, 12, 26);

function isWithinRange(date, range) {
    console.log("isWithinRangeRunning")
    return isWithinInterval(date, { start: range[0], end: range[1] });
}
function isWithinRanges(date, ranges) {
    console.log("isWithinRangesRunning")
    return ranges.some(range => isWithinRange(date, range));
}
let in3Days = new Date(2025, 1, 28);
let in5Days = new Date(2025, 1, 28);
let in13Days = new Date(2025, 1, 26);
let in15Days = new Date(2025, 1, 26);

export default function ContactElectrical({datesUnavailable, setFormStage, timesAvailable, totalPrice, name, phone, email, adults, youth, lessonString, gearString, bikeString, hourString}){

    ///need to reformat dates here before adding to state, or do in useEffect

    const reRef = useRef();
    const [selectedDate, updateSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [serverState, setServerState] = useState({formSent: false});
    const [activeTime, setActiveTime] = useState(0)
    const [bookedDates, setBookedDates] = useState([ [in3Days, in5Days],[in13Days, in15Days],])
    // const [bookedDates, setBookedDates] = useState([ [in3Days, in5Days],[in13Days, in15Days],])

    console.log("datesUnavailable: ", datesUnavailable)
    // console.log("booked", bookedDates)

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log("dates Unavailable running")
            let datesUnavailableRanges = []
            for(let i = 0; i < datesUnavailable.length; i++){
                let d = datesUnavailable[i].bookedDate.split("/")
                //except here they need to be in the right format so I need to seperate and make it so it's like this: new Date(2023, 11, 26);
                datesUnavailableRanges.push([new Date(Number(d[2]), Number(d[1])-1, Number(d[0])), new Date(Number(d[2]), Number(d[1])-1, Number(d[0]))])
            }
            setBookedDates(datesUnavailableRanges);
    },[datesUnavailable])

    // console.log("booked", bookedDates)
    console.log("tile", tileDisabled({date: in3Days, view: "month"}))

    // function tileDisabled({ date, view}) {
    //     console.log("test", view)
    //     console.log("date", date)
    //     console.log("test2", bookedDates)
    //     // Add class to tiles in month view only
    //     if (view === 'month') {
    //       // Check if a date React-Calendar wants to check is within any of the ranges
    //       console.log("test3", isWithinRanges(date, bookedDates))
    //       return isWithinRanges(date, bookedDates);
    //     }
    // }

    function tileDisabled({ date, view}) {
        // Add class to tiles in month view only
        if (view === 'month') {
          // Check if a date React-Calendar wants to check is within any of the ranges
          return isWithinRanges(date, bookedDates);
        }
      }


    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
      } = useForm()


      async function onSubmit(data){
        // const reRef = useRef<>();
        const token = await reRef.current.executeAsync();
        reRef.current.reset();
        let dd = selectedDate.getDate();
        let mm = selectedDate.getMonth()+1;
        let yyyy = selectedDate.getFullYear();
        let reformattedDate = dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;
        fetch("/api/postmark-booking", {
          method: `POST`,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            adults: adults,
            youth: youth,
            lesson: lessonString,
            date: reformattedDate,
            time: timesAvailable[activeTime].time,
            gear: gearString,
            bike: bikeString,
            hours: hourString,
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            token,
        }),
          headers: {
            "content-type": `application/json`,
          },
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(body => {
            console.log(`response from API:`, body);
          })
          .then(setServerState({formSent: true}))
      }
      console.log({ errors })
      useEffect(() => {
          if (serverState.formSent === true) {
            navigate("/booking-success/");
            setTimeout(() => {
                setServerState({
                    formSent: false
                })
            }, 3000)
          }
      })

  return (
            <FormDiv>
                <ReCAPTCHA 
                    sitekey={process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY} 
                    size="invisible"
                    ref={reRef} 
                />
                 <form 
                 onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} 
                 autocomplete="on">

          
                    <label htmlFor="email">BOOKING PERIOD:</label>
                    <DatePicker tileDisabled={tileDisabled} onChange={updateSelectedDate} value={selectedDate}  minDate={new Date(2025, 1, 9)} format="dd-MM-y"/>
                    {/* <DatePicker tileDisabled={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => date.getDay() === 0} /> */}

                    <label>TIME SELECTION:</label>
                    <div className="time-selection">
                        {timesAvailable.map((time, i)=>(
                            <div key={"timeslot "+i} onClick={()=>setActiveTime(i)} className={i === activeTime ? "active-time" : ""}>{time.time}</div>
                        ))}
                    </div>

                    <h3>Total: ${totalPrice}</h3>
                    <p className="recaptcha-sub">This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.</p>
                    
                    <div>
                    <button className="button-style back" onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault();setFormStage(1)}}>BACK</button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => setFormStage(3)}
                        type="submit" 
                        className="g-recaptcha button-style next"
                        data-sitekey="site_key"
                        data-callback='onSubmit'
                        data-action='submit'
                    >
                    SEND REQUEST</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </FormDiv>
  )
}

